# Tls: failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage

Tags: docker

Error Message:

> dockerd: http: TLS handshake error from 10.129.37.6:55989: tls: failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage

Can anyobe please help me why i am receiving the above error message while trying to connect to the docker daemon from the same server as client using:

`curl https://hostname:2376/images/json --cert /data/scripts/mms/server.crt --key /data/scripts/mms/server.key  -v`

Answer (score 0):

Does the server you are connecting expect client certificate?

If Yes, then `--cert /data/scripts/mms/server.crt` should be client certificate and `--key /data/scripts/mms/server.key` should be client key along with `--cacert <server root CA certificate>` (this can be suppressed by passing `-k` option). Corresponding Client certificate chain or Root cert should be present on the server trust store.

If No, then run as below:

`curl https://hostname:2376/images/json --cacert /data/scripts/mms/server.crt -v`. Assuming `server.crt` is server CA cert.